# javascript setInterval is slow in ie8

Tags: javascript

1) chrome, firefox is fine but slow in `IE8`

2) very slow after browser zoom in/out, resize, etc

3) why? memory leak? or ?

```
function moveX(object, coord){
    var v = (coord < 0) ? -1 : 1;

    var timer = setInterval(function(){
        var x = object.offsetLeft + v;
        v *= 2;

        if((v < 0 && x > coord) || (v > 0 && x < coord))
            object.style.left = x + "px";
        else{
            clearInterval(timer);
            object.style.left = coord + "px";
        }
    }, 25);
}
```

Comment: ie8 sucks, it's like 5 years old, javascript runs slow in ie8. http://www.tomshardware.com/reviews/windows-xp-web-browser-performance,3167-7.html

Comment: How fast javasript runs likely is irrelevant here.

Comment: You're probably right, unless their machine itself sucks, regardless, IE8 sucks, it is slow at doing things on the page.

Comment: If `moveX` is called multiple times it will start multiple timers. Make sure thats not happening.

Comment: Do away with IE8 unless there is some real reason to support it.

Comment: use self-calling setTimeouts instead of setInterval, that way it can't get as far behind and (hopefully) perform as poorly.

Comment: IE 8 is over 5 years old, it **should** be much slower than current browsers. Run stuff at jsperf in various browsers and IE 8 will likely be slower than anything else still in use. Get a 5 year old version of Firefox (v3.5), or Chrome (which was a beta) and see how they compare. A 25ms interval means the function is called 40 times per second, is that really necessary? IE's timer only runs at 15ms intervals.

Comment: Trying to use `setTimeout` ?

Answer (score 2):

First off, as was mentioned in the comments, make sure multiple timers aren’t running at the same time. Next, not forcing `offsetLeft` to be calculated each time could also offer quite the speedup.

```
function moveX(object, coord) {
    var v = coord < 0 ? -1 : 1;
    var x = object.offsetLeft;

    var timer = setInterval(function () {
        x += v;
        v *= 2;

        if ((v < 0 && x > coord) || (v > 0 && x < coord)) {
            object.style.left = x + "px";
        } else {
            clearInterval(timer);
            object.style.left = coord + "px";
        }
    }, 25);
}
```

Also, your motion is dependant on how long it takes for the timer to tick; any performance differences might be able to be smoothed over by using time exclusively (though you can’t do this correctly in IE 8; there’s no monotonic timer API):

```
function moveX(object, coord) {
    var v = coord < 0 ? -1 : 1;
    var startX = object.offsetLeft;
    var start = new Date().getTime();

    var timer = setInterval(function () {
        var t = new Date() - start;
        var x = startX + v * Math.pow(2, t / 25);

        if ((v < 0 && x > coord) || (v > 0 && x < coord)) {
            object.style.left = x + "px";
        } else {
            clearInterval(timer);
            object.style.left = coord + "px";
        }
    }, 25);
}
```

That does come at the cost of real performance, though.